# Sikuli: Find Element by Id (or xpath)

Tags: sikuli

I am using Sikuli and for first time I am stuck and need some "light".

I have a div which contains the user profile image, is impossible to visual recognise this with sikuli since the image is changing.  Also I have no other element around that can help me get that element.

I need somehow to get that element by the id and I cannot find any info if such a method exist in Sikuli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sikuli is visual automation tool, works only with images or text found on images (SikuliX). So it does not accept xpath/id etc attributes of elements in a web-page. however if you want to use them please use Selenium Webdriver or Selenium extension with SikuliX.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using sikuli to automate web in first place?
For that, selenium do the job better. Or if you like, a more high level framework: Robotframework/Cucumber/Lettuce with selenium library.

If you really want use sikuli you can try this:
Give it a picture on the side of avatar with a offset.

Example:

GUI: User Xpto [AVATAR] Logout

You can take a picture from logout and give offset to move it:

```
Example not tested: Click [USER]  50  #move right on the x coordinate 
Example not tested: Click [LOGOUT]  -10 #move left on the x coordinate
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore Sikuli-WebDriver. SikuliFirefoxDriver extends Selenium's FirefoxDriver and you can search by id etc. [Read more about Sikuli-WebDriver here.](http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver)

Answer (score 0):

For automating web pages, it is better to use selenium webdriver rather than sikuli.
In webdriver, we can find element by id.
sikuli purely works on visible image, it cannot find any element by its html attributes.